# Salvar dados em formato .xlsx com pandas

Tags: microsoft-excel, pandas

Boa tarde!
Eu quero salvar em uma arquivo .xlsx o número de loop que meu código está rodando, porém da forma que está, salva apenas o último loop.

```
import time
import pandas as pd

loop = 0

print('Loop')

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('/home/pi/Área de Trabalho/saidaCamera3.xlsx')


while True:
        loop = loop + 1

        df = pd.DataFrame({'Loop': [loop]})
        df.to_excel(writer, 'Camera RGB', index=False)
        writer.save()
        if loop>=32:
            break

writer.save()
```

Parece ser meio idiota, porém depois irei juntar com a leitura de meu sensor.

Answer (score 1):

O problema é que a cada passagem no loop, você está criando um `DataFrame` novo.
Mude seu código para o seguinte:

```
import time
import pandas as pd

loop = 0

df = pd.DataFrame()

while True:
    loop = loop + 1
    print('Loop: ', loop)
    df = df.append({'Loop': [loop]}, ignore_index=True)

    if loop >= 32:
        break

print(df.shape)

df.to_excel('/home/pi/Área de Trabalho/saidaCamera3.xlsx', index = False)
```

Perceba que a inicialização do `DataFrame` está fora do *loop*, e que a cada passagem por este, uma nova linha é adicionada.
Ao final do loop, o `DataFrame` é persistido no arquivo Excel.